# Meteor: Debug on server side

Tags: debugging, meteor, server-side

Does anyone know a good method to debug server side code?
I tried enable Node.js debug then use node-inspector but it does not show any of my code.

I end up using console.log but this is very inefficient.

**Update: I found the following procedure works on my Linux machine:**

1. When you run Meteor, it will spawn two processes

   process1: /usr/lib/meteor/bin/node /usr/lib/meteor/app/meteor/meteor.js

   process2: /usr/lib/meteor/bin/node /home/paul/codes/bbtest_code/bbtest02/.meteor/local/build/main.js --keepalive
2. You need to send kill -s USR1 on process2
3. Run node-inspector and you can see your server code

On my first try, I modify the last line on meteor startup script in /usr/lib/meteor/bin/meteor to

```
exec "$DEV_BUNDLE/bin/node" $NODE_DEBUG "$METEOR" "$@"
```

and run `NODE_DEBUG=--debug meteor` on command prompt. This only put --debug flag on process1 so I only see meteor files on node-inspector and could not find my code.

Can someone check this on Windows and Mac machine?

Comment: FYI, instead of console.log, use Meteor._debug (it ends up calling console.log, but there is a note saying that it will be improved some day.)

Comment: See my answer, on MAC it is working, I was able to see and debug my js files.

Comment: I tried this on my Mac, but no go.

Comment: @Harmal000 you linked to this question - did you mean to link to another one?

Comment: This article is really useful about debugging in meteor.js http://joshowens.me/easily-debugging-meteor-js/

Answer (score 88):

In Meteor 0.5.4 this has become a lot easier:

First run the following commands from the terminal:

```
npm install -g node-inspector
node-inspector &
export NODE_OPTIONS='--debug-brk'
meteor
```

And then open `http://localhost:8080` in your browser to view the node-inspector console.

**Update**

Since Meteor 1.0 you can just type

```
meteor debug
```

which is essentially a shortcut for the above commands, and then launch node inspector in your browser as mentioned.

**Update**

In Meteor 1.0.2 a console or shell has been added. It may come in handy to output variables and run commands on the server:

```
meteor shell
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: How do I disable this debugger? Every time I run `meteor` this debugger runs and locks up my meteor app from running anything client-side.

Comment: console outputs always [object Object], for example : `console.log('asd')
[object Object]`

Comment: is it possible to print values? how?

Comment: Is there any official documentation on `meteor debug`. I can't find my code to set a break point.

Answer (score 16):

Meteor apps are Node.js apps. When running a Meteor app with the `meteor [run]` command, you can [configure the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable to start `node` in debug mode](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/412#issuecomment-13536338).

Examples of `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable values:

- `--debug`
- `--debug=47977` - specify a port
- `--debug-brk` - break on the first statement
- `--debug-brk=5858` - specify a port and break on the first statement

If you `export NODE_OPTIONS=--debug`, all `meteor` command run from the same shell will inherit the environment variable. Alternatively, you can enable debugging just for one run, with `NODE_OPTIONS="--debug=47977" meteor`.

To debug, run `node-inspector` in a different shell, then go to `http://localhost:8080/debug?port=<the port you specified in NODE_OPTIONS>`, regardless of what `node-inspector` tells you to run.

Answer (score 10):

To start node.js in debug mode, I did it this way:

1. open /usr/lib/meteor/app/meteor/run.js
2. before

   ```
   nodeOptions.push(path.join(options.bundlePath, 'main.js'));
   ```

   add

   ```
   nodeOptions.push('--debug');
   ```

Here are additional practical steps for your to attach debugger eclipse:

1. use '--debug-brk' instead of '--debug' here, because it's easier for me to attach node.js using eclipse as debugger.
2. add 'debugger;' in the code where you want to debug.(I prefer this way personally)
3. run meteor in console
4. attach to node.js in eclipse(V8 tools, attach to localhost:5858)
5. run, wait for debugger to be hit

when you start meteor in your meteor app folder, you'll see that "*debugger listening on port 5858*" in console.

Comment: if you're using mrt, of course the path to run.js is different.

Comment: ... as in ~/.meteorite/meteors/meteor/meteor/0a148c69d6af9832006a6f6d27cc112ed90cb3e4/app/meteor/

Comment: My files are duplicated in `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/` by unknown reasons.
If it doesn't work to you, try editing `/usr/local/meteor/app/meteor/run.js` instead of `/usr/lib/meteor/app/meteor/run.js`

Comment: Thanks, your solution is the easiest I ever found. It doesn't require to be killing process, neither set variables over the command line.

Answer (score 10):

On Meteor 1.0.3.1 (update to Sergey.Simonchik answer)

Start your server with `meteor run --debug-port=<port-number>`

Point browser to `http://localhost:6222/debug?port=<port-number>`

Where `<port-number>` is a port you specify.

In your code add a `debugger;` where you want to set your break point.

Depending on where `debugger;` is invoked, it will either break on your client or server browser window with inspector opened.

Answer (score 7):

I like to set breakpoints via a GUI. This way I don't have to remember to remove any debugging code from my app.

This is how I managed to do it server side for my local meteor app:

```
meteor debug
```

start your app this way.

**Open Chrome to the address it gives you.** You MAY need to install https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector (it might come bundled with Meteor now? not sure)

You'll see some weird internal meteor code (not the app code you wrote). **Press play** to run the code. This code simply starts up your server to listen for connections.

Only after you press play you'll see a new directory in your debugger folder structure called **"app"**. In there are your meteor project files. Set a breakpoint in there one the line you want.

**Open the local address of your app**. This will run your server side code and you you should be able to hit your breakpoint!

Note: you have to reopen the inspector and go through this process again each time your app restarts!

Answer (score 6):

As of Meteor 1.0.2 probably the best way for server-side debugging is directly via the new built-in shell: with running server run `meteor shell`. More info here: https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/12/19/meteor-102-meteor-shell

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure why it was not working for you.
I am able to use it by following steps on console (Mac).

```
$ ps  
$ kill -s USR1 *meteor_node_process_id*  
$ node-inspector &
```

Above steps are mentioned on https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector.  It is for attaching node-inspector to running node process.

Comment: I have tested on Mac only, are you using Mac?

Comment: Yeah, I have a Mac.
How do you add the breakpoint in code? What are the exact steps you use for the whole thing?

Comment: after above (this answer's) steps, I start the inspector.
$ node-inspector &
opened http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858 in chrome.
I was able to see my files in source tab in webkit-inspector

Comment: I've tried this, adding both `debugger` and breakpoints in the inspector, but neither of them worked. Any idea why?

Comment: When look at `ps | grep node` (or similar) make sure you pick the main.js pid to signal, not it's parent node process. This is how I got it to work.

Comment: from what I remember `&` operator does launch process in the background as in Linux.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a small meteor package called *meteor-inspector* which simplifies the use of node-inspector to debug meteor apps. It internally manages the lifecycle of node-inspector and hence, the user does not need to restart the debugger manually after some files have changed.

For more details and concrete usage instructions take a look at https://github.com/broth-eu/meteor-inspector.

Answer (score 4):

for meteor 1.3.5.2, run

> meteor debug --debug-port 5858+n
>   n is a non-zero number, this will cause node-inspector use 8080+n as web port.

Answer (score 3):

[WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751080/how-can-i-debug-my-meteor-app-using-the-webstorm-ide), the powerful IDE free for open source developers, makes it much easier to debug server-side.

I've tested it on Windows, and the configuration was painless - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751080/how-can-i-debug-my-meteor-app-using-the-webstorm-ide).

Answer (score 3):

A inspector that solve my issues is meteor server console. Here is the process I followed to install it:

1. In your project folder, add the smart package `server-eval`:

   ```
   mrt add server-eval
   ```

   For Meteor 1.0:

   ```
   meteor add gandev:server-eval
   ```
2. Restart meteor.
3. Download `crx` Chrome extension file from [here](https://github.com/gandev/meteor-server-console/releases).
4. Open extensions page in Chrome and drag `crx` file to extensions page.
5. Restart Chrome.
6. Check the web inspector out to eval server side code:

   [image]

In comparison with node-inspector, I have a clearer output.

Comment: from what I remember it worked with breakpoints, but I am not sure.

Comment: do you remember how you set them? via dev tools or incode?

Comment: dev tools, but don't remember exactly how

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to use [nodeJS' official debugger](http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) you can call `NODE_OPTIONS='--debug' meteor` and then (on a different shell) `node debug localhost:5858`.