# meteor logs <site>

Tags: authentication, logging, meteor

I am starting with meteor [version 0.3.8 (7510b8430e) on OSX] and cloned one of the examples. I peppered my server side with a couple of console.log() statements and am trying to look at the output. According to the manual it is

```
meteor logs <site>
```

but that command asks for a authentication? What am I missing?

Comment: just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034941/meteor-debug-on-server-side but it does not answer my question

Comment: Metor._debug() at least logs to stderr, so I can see what is going on. I am still wondering what authentication is being used with the command meteor logs <site>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you at some point run

```
meteor deploy yoursite --password
```

or

```
meteor deploy yoursite -P
```

? If so, it's the password that you set at that time. If you're sure you didn't, maybe somebody else beat you to it (since anyone can set the password on a deployed app with no password)?

Comment: no, it is just running on my local development instance, but I suspect now where this is going :)

Comment: Right, `meteor logs` is to retrieve logs from a site deployed with `meteor deploy`. When running an app with just `meteor`, server-side `console.log` should just be printed to stdout.