# Meteor: Best debugging tool?

Tags: meteor

I'm learning how to use Meteor and am coming from some basic/intermediate python/django knowledge.

What's the best debugging tool in Meteor, perhaps one that can let you pause the code in the middle of execution and let you walk through? I'm thinking something like ipdb in python...

Comment: the newest version of meteor has made that easier have a look at [that answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909610/how-to-debug-server-side-code-in-a-meteor-app/14909616#14909616

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the client, use your browser's developer tools to set breakpoints and step through code.

On the server, since Meteor runs on node.js, you could use [node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector), which hooks into your browser's developer tools. See [Meteor: Debug on server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034941/meteor-debug-on-server-side) for more info on how to get node-inspector working.