# Server side database debugging in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I am debugging my meteor server as described here: [How to debug server side code in a Meteor app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909610/how-to-debug-server-side-code-in-a-meteor-app)

When I try to make a database query I get the following error.  How do I investigate the database on the server?

```
>Meteor.users.find({_id:"HM3JWNm3D2GYMRqZfz"}).fetch()
Error: Can't wait without a fiber
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have put a break point in a Router function or something similar? I just tried and querying collections in the console worked for me

Comment: No, I don't have any breakpoints.  Should I be querying from inside a breakpoint?

Comment: yes, or else you have no context. If all you need is check the database, you can use the `meteor mongo` command in your app folder

Answer (score 3):

1. Start your app with:

   ```
   $ meteor
   ```
2. Open a new Terminal window and type:

   ```
   $ meteor mongo
   ```

This will open the serverside mongo database console.

**FYI:**

If you deployed your app to meteor you can access its database console via:

```
   $ meteor mongo myapp
```

Comment: so i got the console, but is there a log anywhere or live feedback?