# How to debug Meteor in IntelliJ

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, intellij-idea, meteor

I want to debug javascript code of Meteor apps in IntelliJ.

I read the instructions in the following tutorials:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/running-and-debugging-node-js.html

http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Remote_JavaScript_debugging_with_WebStorm_and_PHPStorm

The first tutorial explains debugging a Node.js application. The second tutorial explains debugging a javascript application.

Could someone explain how to debug meteor apps in Intellij?

Answer (score 2):

there is an instruction [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6264) (please add your vote) but the issue is you need to restart the debugger every time you make a change because meteor restarts the nodejs process.

starting your application with ´NODE_OPTION="--debug"´ allows you to debug in ´node-inspector´ with the same limitation (restart after every change). [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909610/how-to-debug-server-side-code-in-a-meteor-app/14909616#14909616)

My experience with IntelliJ is that even if restarted every time, the javascript debugger will struggle to reconnect. I use IntelliJ for development but [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) for debugging.