# Debugging meteor app - setup node inspector

Tags: node.js, meteor, intellij-14, node-inspector

I wanted to debug meteor code and came across couple of links:

[How to debug server side code in a Meteor app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909610/how-to-debug-server-side-code-in-a-meteor-app/14909616#14909616)

https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#how-do-i-debug-my-meteor-app

While these two links talks about using node inspector to debug the code, it does not tells you how to run the actual application and setup the break point.

I am able to run\setup node inspector but I am not sure after that how can I launch the application and set breakpoints. Please help

Comment: You can no use `meteor shell` to do server side debugging.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meteor: Debug on server side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034941/meteor-debug-on-server-side)