# Debug Meteor server side in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, intellij-idea, webstorm

I have followed [these instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/run-debug-configuration-meteor.html) to debug Meteor JS in WebStorm. This allows me to debug client side JavaScript code in my IDE, but I want to also import the server side JavaScript code.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909610/how-to-debug-server-side-code-in-a-meteor-app). Debugging server side in browser works, but is there also a way to debug both, server and client side in WebStorm?