# How to configure WebStorm to debug meteor server files?

Tags: meteor, webstorm

How can I configure webstorm to debug meteor server files?

Comment: or any other way to debug meteor ...

Comment: Check the [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11034941/104891). You can use [Node JS Remote Debug configuration](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-node-js-remote-debug.html) in WebStorm.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug my Meteor app using the WebStorm IDE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751080/how-can-i-debug-my-meteor-app-using-the-webstorm-ide)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it working with PHPStorm. See: [WEB-6264](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6264#comment=27-445048) I did have to make a slight modification to the configuration though.

1. Install NodeJS plugin from the Plugin Repository
2. Create a Node.js Remote Debug run configuration and fill in the fields:

   - Host : 127.0.0.1 (host of meteor app running, leave untouched if meteor is running on your local machine)
   - Debug port : 5858
   - Local directory : /path/to/your/meteor/project
   - Remote path : app
3. NODE_OPTIONS="--debug" meteor

Comment: I can't get this to work in WebStorm 7. It no longer has "local directory" and "remote path" options so perhaps that has something to do with it. Anyone else got it working?

Comment: As of WebStorm 9+, this answer is fortunately outdated. Debugging Meteor apps with Webstorm is much easier - see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21571249/1269037).