# How can I debug my Meteor app using the WebStorm IDE?

Tags: node.js, debugging, meteor, remote-debugging, webstorm

Can anyone provide a short list of steps on how to connect a Meteor app to the WebStorm debugger please?

Comment: To debug meteor app in IDE, you can do following: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6264#comment=27-445048

Comment: [WebStorm has had Meteor support](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeqkGF3Z7rU) for a few months now. @BenjaminRH, can you please remove the old comment? Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

WebStorm is the only IDE with native support for debugging Meteor server code - check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeqkGF3Z7rU). Even on Windows, debugging is very simple:

## WebStorm 9+

Go to Run --> Debug --> Edit configurations... , click the plus sign, click "Meteor". You can add environment variable like ROOT_URL if you need to.

---

## WebStorm older than 9

This answer is kept only for historical purposes. You should upgrade WebStorm.

On older WebStorms, you used to have to create a Node.js debugging configuration.

- on the server, export the environment variable `NODE_OPTIONS=--debug=47977`. For instance,

  ```
  NODE_OPTIONS=--debug=47977 meteor  # Linux/Mac
  set NODE_OPTIONS=--debug=47977 & meteor`  # Windows
  ```
- create a WebStorm/PhpStorm Run/Debug configuration using the port above (47977) and the server host. Leave 127.0.0.1 if you're debugging locally.

[image: Run -> Run/Debug confioguration]

- in WebStorm, Run -> Debug <myapp>, or press Shift+F9. Make sure that you see "Connected to <your host> in the Debug panel

Now you can set breakpoints, have access to local variables etc.

For client debugging, just use the Chrome debugger, or Firebug.

### Troubleshooting

- `Process disconnected unexpectedly` - this happens when meteor restarts automatically because of lack of specific support for Meteor. Just Run -> Debug <myapp>, or press Shift+F9 again.
- you can't connect to the server - make sure the firewall rules allow incoming connections to whatever port you chose for the Node.js debugger (47977 here).

Comment: Just an extra note that the `Share` option in the run configuration is important too. I missed that one.

Comment: @Pie21: would you know what that option does? It has no tooltip and if I recall correctly, it didn't make a difference on my setup.

Comment: @DanDascalescu: To be honest, even with the checkbox it still didn't catch break points for me, but it did at least say "connected". I didn't do any very rigorous testing, and it might have just been restarting the debugger that fixed the connection, but I assume it means that you can have multiple debuggers on the same port, or something. I'm the wrong person to ask; my comment was perhaps a bit of false confidence :).

Comment: Does not work for me, even with the share checkbox. I get "Cannot connect" in Variables. I'm remotely connecting to a Meteor 0.8.0.1 server and tried disabling firewall entirely.

Comment: Does not work for me with Meteor 0.9.3 and WebStorm 9
It says connecting to localhost, but never connects.
Checked firewall to be off both on Windows and on linux/precise32/vagrant

Answer (score 11):

The other answers are now out of date. Don't add a Node.js debug configuration as described above, or bother with spyjs.

If you're using Webstorm 9.0, it's as simple as going to Run --> Debug --> Edit configurations... , click the plus, click "Meteor".

WebStorm may also ask you to install a browser add-on, but that's just for client-side debugging; just add a breakpoint in the server-side code and you'll see it works out of the box.

JetBrains have updated [the video which was linked to](http://youtu.be/yeqkGF3Z7rU) in Dan Dascalescu's answer above, and it shows you the process I just described.

Answer (score 5):

For applications using `webpack:webpack`, using WebStorm's `Meteor` debug profile did not seem to work.

My setup uses `webpack:webpack` v1.0.12, Meteor v1.3.0 and WebStorm 2016.1, but is likely to work with later versions (note that a fix for just this issue was released in v1.0.12, so earlier versions are likely not to work with this procedure).

Here is what I did in order to get it working:

1. Create a `webpack.json` file at the project root.

   It should include the `devtool` config, which generates source maps that assist in debugging. The rest may be changed according to your specific setup.

   ```
   {
     "root": "src",
     "devServer": {
       "host": "localhost"
     },
     "devtool": "source-map"
   }
   ```
2. Create a debug setup:

   Node.js Remote Debug, port `5858` (the port is configurable).

   [image: remote node debug configuration]
3. Run `meteor debug`

   You may specify a port using `--debug-port <port number>`.

   See `meteor help debug` for the full details.

   [image: meteor debug first run]
4. Connect WebStorm to the debugger

   - start the debugger
     [image: click "debug"]
   - the status message should indicate that it is connected. Scripts should available in the `Scripts` tab.
     [image: the debug panel should state that it is connected]
   - the server should be running in the console
     [image: server should resume execution]
5. Hit your breakpoints and rejoice.

Answer (score 3):

WebStorm 9 will have Meteor support. While WS 9 isn't released yet (as of Oct 7, 2014), there is an [early access program for WS 9](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+9+EAP).

Read the JetBrains WebStorm blog which [describes some of the Meteor support features](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/09/meteor-support-in-webstorm-9/) and includes a brief video.

I'm new to Meteor, WebStorm (and JavaScript for that matter) and have been using the WS 9 EAP build 138.2406 for a couple of weeks. I can launch my project from within the IDE, set breakpoints, walk though code, inspect values, jump to definitions, and issue completions. It's quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try spyjs plugin for Webstorm: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/04/spy-js-webstorm-secret-service/

Comment: SpyJS, while a useful too, does something else.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19334) with old versions of Webstorm to debug server-side of Meteor 1.2.x. The latest version of Webstorm (11.0.3) released on Dec 24th, 2015 fixed it. Release notes can be found here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+143.1559.5+Release+Notes

I am now able to debug without any problem from Webstorm :)