# How do I debug server-side meteor code with Webstorm 7

Tags: coffeescript, meteor, webstorm

I'm having some trouble getting server-side debugging of my Meteor project working with Webstorm 7.

I've read [this jetbrains support article](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6264#comment=27-445048) for Webstorm 6. Webstorm 7 has simplified the node.js remote debug options and there is no longer an option to enter a local directory and remote path.

I've tried:

1. Running meteor with the node debugger options:

   $ NODE_OPTIONS="--debug=47977" meteor
2. Setting up a node.js remote debug configuration in Webstorm, pointing it at the same port (47977).
3. Launching the debug session
4. Setting breakpoints in my coffeescript source files - no dice, never hits breakpoints.
5. Setting breakpoints in the meteor generated js files in .meteor/local/build/programs/server/app - no dice either.

Has anyone got this working? Obviously it would be ideal to be able to debug directly in my coffeescript, but I'd settle for the js at this point!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug my Meteor app using the WebStorm IDE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751080/how-can-i-debug-my-meteor-app-using-the-webstorm-ide)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the closest I got was to:

1. Run meteor with the node debugger options:

   $ NODE_OPTIONS="--debug=47977" meteor
2. Setup a node.js remote debug configuration in Webstorm, pointing it at the same port (47977).
3. Launch a debug session
4. Set my breakpoints in the transpiled js files shown in the debugger's "scripts" tab. Confusingly, when setting breakpoints on these files, my version of WebStorm (8.0.4) did not show the usual red circle icon in the gutter... but it did set the breakpoint and break there.

So not ideal, but still better than nothing while we wait for official Meteor support from JetBrains (and more convenient than using node-inspector).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if using coffeescript would change this but [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526920/how-to-configure-webstorm-to-debug-meteor-server-files/15594528) is what I did to get it working.

Comment: I'm using WebStorm version 7. It does not have local directory and remote path options when setting up the node remote debug config.