# Way to debug Meteor code?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I would like to debug Meteor code with simple `console.log` and some code changing, to see if I can pinpoint the problem. But when I edit .meteor/local/build/app/packages/livedata/ file, for example, it is overriden back by Meteorite, when I run it again. What is the best way to just temporary change the running code?

[Explains how to attach with debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034941/meteor-debug-on-server-side), but I am interested in more a better local development cycle. So that I can run my own Meteor app but fix code a bit also in Meteor, to see how things interact.

I suspect that the issue is with Meteorite, which replaces code automatically so it is not possible to run Meteor with local changes?

Comment: I don't think it's an exact duplicate but the options in that question seem better than using `console.log`.

Comment: Files used by Meteorite are in `.meteorite/source/meteor/meteor/packages/`

Comment: There are different ways you want to debug. In my case I wanted to change some code and see what happens. But it seems Meteorite simply clears every time the Meteor code with version from the repository.

Comment: Webstorm supports Meteor debugging