# console.log in .meteor directory

Tags: meteor, meteorite, console.log

Sometimes I want to analyze how things works in a meteor app and I wish I could output logs in the .meteor directory. But If I add a console.log() there, it never shows. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034941/meteor-debug-on-server-side

Comment: and http://observatoryjs.com/

Comment: Thx for the links, very useful for a beginner. Observatory looks very interesting. Actually I wanted to debug the code that I don't own in the core packages copied in .meteor directory. Each time I add alog there, it's automatically removed after a while.

Answer (score 0):

As of the current version of Meteor, you can use a normal debugger on the server side using `meteor debug`. (You could always use the debugger client-side by using the Web Inspector.)