# meteor debug not working : just BREAKPOINTS not working

Tags: meteor

I have tried out `all the possibilities` listed at [Meteor: Debug on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034941/meteor-debug-on-server-side), i am able to see the console. BUT breakpoints are not working in sources.(In all cases)

Also when the server starts up. It pauses at 
module.js line 456

```
return compiledWrapper.apply(self.exports, args);
```

I am getting this in console.

```
Debugger.setSkipAllPauses failed. Error: Not implemented.
Debugger.setSkipAllPauses failed. Error: Not implemented.
Runtime.getProperties failed. Object #-34# not found
Debugger.setSkipAllPauses failed. Error: Not implemented.
Debugger.setSkipAllPauses failed. Error: Not implemented.
Debugger.setSkipAllPauses failed. Error: Not implemented.
Debugger.setSkipAllPauses failed. Error: Not implemented.
Debugger.setSkipAllPauses failed. Error: Not implemented.
Runtime.getProperties failed. Object #-37# not found
Debugger.setSkipAllPauses failed. Error: Not implemented.
Debugger.setSkipAllPauses failed. Error: Not implemented.
Runtime.getProperties failed. Object #-38# not found
Runtime.getProperties failed. Object #-39# not found
Debugger.setSkipAllPauses failed. Error: Not implemented.
Debugger.setSkipAllPauses failed. Error: Not implemented.
Debugger.setSkipAllPauses failed. Error: Not implemented.
Debugger.setSkipAllPauses failed. Error: Not implemented.
Debugger.setSkipAllPauses failed. Error: Not implemented.
Runtime.getProperties failed. Object #-43# not found
Runtime.getProperties failed. Object #-44# not found
Runtime.getProperties failed. Object #-45# not found
```

Has got something to do in Chrome or in Meteor ??

Comment: is it related to node-inspected version ?? Saw few links, i tried my self downgrading the version and restarting node inspector but did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

> Use node <=0.10.33 or wait 0.10.36

https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/522