# unable to debug meteor app , can see server side code but breakpoints doesn't work

Tags: meteor

WEIRD HAPPENING.. I am unable to debug meteor app , BREAKPOINTS doesn't work in chrome(can see the server side sources thou).. I have already wasted 2 days over it ..

I have already tried
[Meteor: Debug on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034941/meteor-debug-on-server-side)

Also tried similar options changing web-port and other options.

Also tried to reduce the node-inspector version, BUT breakpoints are not working for me..

any suggestions on how to debug this issue?

(Chrome browser, ubuntu, AMD machine, if that matters)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. The only workaround I've found is to put `debugger;` statements in my code. Those *are* respected and treated as breakpoints which stop the server for Node Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [observatory](https://github.com/jhoxray/observatory) or [read this article](http://meteorhacks.com/debugging-meteor-packages-and-apps.html), maybe it'll helps

Comment: nice but not really useful .

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone. [There is an issue posted to github about this,](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1411) and it appears to be confirmed by several users.

I was able to get Node Inspector to work a while ago by [downgrading to 1.10](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/MeaC-E_Sj6Q). It's not as nice as the new version but worked last time I used it. I honestly haven't needed it recently, but hopefully it'll still work.

Comment: The interface is different; is it possible you're overlooking the files? Under Scripts, there is a select box that when clicked will list all js files alphabetically. It will include all the Meteor files as well, but yours should be there. If there is nothing in the select box, then it's a different problem.

Comment: Another possibility: are you setting NODE_OPTIONS. I'm assuming you are, since you could see your files before, but [there are instructions here](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/6ed3ec0a-ac56-4fdb-8be0-f415c330d03c) if you need them.

Comment: Github issue fixed and closed in July 2014.